# Checking the result of a postgres query from Bash

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm having issues parsing the outputs of a postgres sql query from bash script.

Here is the output from a command line query to postgres:

```
root@API:/home# psql -U postgres -h pgipaddress -c "SELECT 1 AS __ROW__ FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='postgres'"
 __row__ 
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

Here is what the variable `$userexists` looks like before you look at the conditions:

`__row__ --------- 1 (1 row)`

Here are my attempts at string conditional checking:

```
userexists=$(psql -U postgres -h ${pgip} -c "SELECT 1 AS __ROW__ FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='postgres'")
if [ "${userexists}" == "__row__\n---------\n1 \n(1 row)"* ] ; then
  printf "Database User exists\n"
else
  printf "Database User does not exists\n"
fi

userexists=$(psql -U postgres -h ${pgip} -c "SELECT 1 AS __ROW__ FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='postgres'")
if [ "${userexists}" == "__row__ --------- 1 (1 row)"* ] ; then
  printf "Database User exists\n"
else
  printf "Database User does not exists\n"
fi
```

All result in database user does not exist.

Comment: Have you considered using `--quiet -tA` flags, which would reduce your output to just `1` and nothing else?

Comment: perfect works great. only problem is if the user does not exist postgres issues an error on the console. i tried redirecting errors to /dev/null but when i do that i dont get output anymore

Comment: How about using `count()`?

Comment: actually that error was separate. make this an answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `userexists` are likely to actually contain the linebreaks, but you probably checked the contents with an unquoted expansion:

```
# Assignment
$ userexists=' __row__
---------
       1
(1 row)'

$ echo "$userexists"  # Quoted expansion
 __row__
---------
       1
(1 row)

$ echo $userexists    # Unquoted expansion squashes whitespace
__row__ --------- 1 (1 row)
```

Additionally, if you want to compare two strings containing linebreaks with `[ ... ]`, you can't use `"\n"` to insert a linebreak. ANSI-C escapes, `$'\n'`, would work:

```
var='has
linebreak'
[ "$var" = $'has\nlinebreak' ] && echo 'Match'
```

prints `Match`. Two remarks: Bash will understand `==` when used in `[ ]`, but it's not portable, so `=` is recommended. Also, `[ ]` doesn't support pattern matching, so the `*` at the end of your right-hand side won't do what you expect. `[[ ]]` and `case` can be used for pattern matching.

To avoid the whole problem in the first place, you can supply a few flags to `psql`, specifically:

- `--quiet` – no informational output
- `-t` – tuples only; no column names, result count footers etc.
- `-A` – unaligned output (removes leading blank from line)

and the return from your command will be just `1` and you can compare with

```
if [ "$userexists" = 1 ]; then
```